# How do I solve this error in sum of square python program for finding second largest number in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def get_second_largest(num):
    largest = num[0]
    second_largest = num[0]
    while i < len(num) :
        if num[i] > largest:
            second_largest = largest
            largest = num[i]
        elif num[i] > second_largest:
            second_largest = nums[i]
return second_largest


i = int(input("Enter Numbers "))
list_1 = list(i.split(" ,"))

second_largest = get_second_largest(list_1)
print("Second largest number is :", second_largest)
```

---

What I am getting

```
Enter Numbers 5 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python through atom\Find_The_Second_Largest_Num.py", line 15, in <module>
    second_largest = get_second_largest(list_1)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python through atom\Find_The_Second_Largest_Num.py", line 4, in get_second_largest
    while i < len(num) :
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are reading some input using the Python built-in function, it converts the input in to a string (stripping the trailing newline) and returns that. [Official Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

```
>>> i = input("-->")
-->1 ,2 , 4 ,8
>>> i
'1 ,2 , 4 ,8'
>>> i.split(" ,")
['1', '2', ' 4', '8']
```

Performing explicit conversion from `string` to `int` while splitting will resolve your error.

```
>>> l = [int(n) for n in i.split(" ,")]
>>> l
[1, 2, 4, 8]
```

*A few other things to point out:*

1. `int(input("Enter Input"))` throws a ValueError because as mentioned in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), input function returns a string.
2. `list(i.split(" ,"))` By default [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) returns a list of words. So there is no need for explicit conversion to list.
3. A more pythonic way to achieve your goal (which is to find the second largest number) would be to leverage the [sort()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) / [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) built-in functions along with list indexes. (as suggested by @mohideen-bin-mohammed)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do,

```
>>> inp = input("Enter numbers:")
Enter numbers:10 100 200 20 30 40 11 20 1 54 300
>>> _inp_list = [int(i) for i in inp.split()]
>>> _inp_list.sort()
>>> _inp_list[-2]
200
>>>
```

Your mistake is,
You are comparing string with string i.e `'10' > '20'`
this will lead to error in python 3 but it might work in python 2.
you wont able to do **><** with string . comparison should be with integers